# SQL query on similarity

Tags: sql

I have to display all the customers who have been referred by a referrer with the same last name as the customer.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I added a photo of the data

Comment: I guess desired result would spit out customer 1019 as he is smith and was referred by 1003 who is also a smith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `self-join` as

```
select c1.customer#, c1.lastname, c1.city, c1.zip, c1.referred 
  from customers c1 
  join customers c2 
    on c1.customer# = c2.referred
   and c1.lastname = c2.lastname;

customer#   lastname    city       zip     referred
---------   --------  -----------  ------  ---------
1003        SMITH     TALLAHASSEE   32306   NULL
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/ACEJF79077)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query

```
select cust.*, cust_ref.*
from customers cust,
referred cust_ref
where cust_ref.lastname = cust.lastname
```

Note : You can select field according your requirement.

I hope it will used.